# How to merge few python scripts into one?

Tags: python-2.7, merge

I am newbie when it comes to programming and python.
Therefore I've got a question. With my fellow students we have created few python scripts but now we are stuck and have no more ideas. We need to merge few python scripts into one working scripts. Could anyone help us with that, please?
Scripts:

```
# Script: webpage_get.py
# Desc: Fetches data from a webpage, and parses out hyperlinks.
# Author: Wojciech Kociszewski
# Created: Nov, 2013
#
import sys, urllib

def wget(url):
    ''' Try to retrieve a webpage via its url, and return its contents'''
    print '[*] wget()'
    #open file like url object from web, based on url
    url_file = urllib.urlopen(url)
    # get webpage contents
    page = url_file.read()
    return page

def main():
    #temp testing url argument
    sys.argv.append('http://www.soc.napier.ac.uk/~cs342/CSN08115/cw_webpage/index.html')
    #check args
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print '[-] Usage: webpage_get URL'
        return

    #Get and analyse web page
    print wget(sys.argv[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
# Script: webpage_getlinks.py
# Desc: Basic web site info gathering and analysis script. From a URL gets
# page content, parsing links out.
# Author: Wojciech Kociszewski
# Created: Nov, 2013
#
import sys, re
import webpage_get

def print_links(page):
    ''' find all hyperlinks on a webpage passed in as input and print '''
    print '[*] print_links()'
    # regex to match on hyperlinks, returning 3 grps, links[1] being the link itself
    links = re.findall(r'(\<a.*href\=.*)(http\:.+)(?:[^\'" >]+)', page)
    # sort and print the links
    links.sort()
    print '[+]', str(len(links)), 'HyperLinks Found:'
    for link in links:
        print link[1]

def main():
    # temp testing url argument
    sys.argv.append('http://www.soc.napier.ac.uk/~cs342/CSN08115/cw_webpage/index.html')
    # Check args
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print '[-] Usage: webpage_getlinks URL'
        return

    # Get the web page
    page = webpage_get.wget(sys.argv[1])
    # Get the links
    print_links(page)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
# Script: webpage_getemails.py
# Desc: Basic web site info gathering and analysis script. From a URL gets
# page content, parsing emails out.
# Author: Wojciech Kociszewski
# Created: Nov, 2013
#
import sys, re
import webpage_get

def print_emails(page):
    ''' find all emails on a webpage passed in as input and print '''
    print '[*] print_emails()'
    # regex to match on emails
    emails = re.findall(r'([\d\w\.-_]+@[\w\d\.-_]+\.\w+)', page)
    # sort and print the emails
    emails.sort()
    print '[+]', str(len(emails)), 'Emails Found:'
    for email in emails:
        print email

def main():
    # temp testing url argument
    sys.argv.append('http://www.soc.napier.ac.uk/~cs342/CSN08115/cw_webpage/index.html')
    # Check args
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print '[-] Usage: webpage_getemails'
        return

    # Get the web page
    page = webpage_get.wget(sys.argv[1])
    # Get the emails
    print_emails(page)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Post them here and maybe we can provide suggestions to specific questions. Otherwise, probably not. You could try codereview.stackexchange.com after you've combined them.

Answer (score 0):

Analyse your scripts and find the common code

Convert the common code into a module

Rewrite the individual programs with the common code

If you then wish to make the individual programs into one big program it will be much easier